# Calculate the dimensions of a rotated rectangle inside a bounding box

Tags: trigonometry

[image: Rotated rectangle inside a bounding box]

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to calculate the width & height of the gray rectangle if I only know the width & height of the dotted red rectangle and the angle of the rotation.

I've tried substituting values for the width and height and using $x \cos(\alpha) + y \sin(\alpha)$ and attempting to figure out a scaling factor, but I'm not really getting anywhere.

Comment: Could you draw a figure where you indicate the name of the variables (say $h, w,x,y,\alpha$)? That way I can write the appropriate formula. Or at least indicate which one is which.

Comment: Thanks @Andrei, updated as requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$x\cos\alpha+y\sin\alpha=w\\x\sin\alpha+y\cos\alpha=h$$
Multiply first equation by $\cos\alpha$, the second by $\sin\alpha$ and subtract:
$$x(\cos^2\alpha-\sin^2\alpha)=w\cos\alpha-h\sin\alpha$$or $$x=\frac{w\cos\alpha-h\sin\alpha}{\cos^2\alpha-\sin^2\alpha}$$
Similarly, multiply the first equation by $\sin\alpha$, the second by $\cos\alpha$ and subtract:
$$y(\sin^2\alpha-\cos^2\alpha)=w\sin\alpha-h\cos\alpha\\y=\frac{w\sin\alpha-h\cos\alpha}{\sin^2\alpha-\cos^2\alpha}$$
Notice that the denominator might be $0$ for $\alpha=45^\circ$. Then you must have the numerator equal to $0$ as well, or $w=h$, so you have a square inside a square $x=y$ and $$2x\frac{\sqrt 2}2=w$$ or $$x=w\frac{\sqrt 2}2$$

Comment: Thank you so much @Andrei, appreciate your fast response.

Comment: When rotated 45 degrees there are no unique result and it also not necessarily a square.